Material UI custom colors
Goodmorning everybody,
I am trying to develop a website using ReactJS and Material UI.
I started from this template.
I would like to modify the color of the TextField when focused: now it is blue, let's say that I want it to be green.
This was the original file (in the repo that i linked above, it is under src/components/MKInput/MKInputRoot):
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default styled(TextField)(({ theme, ownerState }) => {
  const { palette, functions } = theme;
  const { error, success, disabled } = ownerState;

  const { grey, transparent, error: colorError, success: colorSuccess } = palette;
  const { pxToRem } = functions;

  // styles for the input with error={true}
  const errorStyles = () => ({
    backgroundImage:
      "url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23F44335' viewBox='0 0 12 12'%3E%3Ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3E%3Cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23F44335' stroke='none'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: `right ${pxToRem(12)} center`,
    backgroundSize: `${pxToRem(16)} ${pxToRem(16)}`,

    "& .Mui-focused": {
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline, &:after": {
        borderColor: colorError.main,
      },
    },

    "& .MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused": {
      color: colorError.main,
    },
  });

  // styles for the input with success={true}
  const successStyles = () => ({
    backgroundImage:
      "url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 10 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%234CAF50' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: `right ${pxToRem(12)} center`,
    backgroundSize: `${pxToRem(16)} ${pxToRem(16)}`,

    "& .Mui-focused": {
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline, &:after": {
        borderColor: colorSuccess.main,
      },
    },

    "& .MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused": {
      color: colorSuccess.main,
    },
  });

  return {
    backgroundColor: disabled ? `${grey[200]} !important` : transparent.main,
    pointerEvents: disabled ? "none" : "auto",
    ...(error && errorStyles()),
    ...(success && successStyles()),
  };
});

I simplified it a little:
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default styled(TextField)(({ theme, ownerState }) => {
  const { palette } = theme;
  const { disabled } = ownerState;

  const { grey, transparent } = palette;

  const myStyles = () => ({
    "& .Mui-focused": {
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline, &:after": {
        borderColor: "#00ff00",
      },
    },

    "& .MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused": {
      color: "#00ff00",
    },
  });

  return {
    backgroundColor: disabled ? `${grey[200]} !important` : transparent.main,
    pointerEvents: disabled ? "none" : "auto",
    ...myStyles(),
  };
});

I removed the error && before ...myStyle() as I want this style to always be appliend, not only on error.
Now suppose I want to change from green to red, I replace the strings "#00ff00" with "#ff0000", click on the text input on my webpage and the border becomes red when focused. If I refresh the page and do that again, the border is blue on focus. This happens every time I try to change color: I replace the color string with the desired one, and the correct color is applied until I refresh the page; after refresh, focus border color always goes back to blue.
Any suggestion on why this may happen?
EDIT:
Looks like the color is taken from primary property of the theme. I have tried different ways to override this behaviour, like using styleOverrides when creating the theme:
export default createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& .Mui-focused": {
            borderColor: (props) => {
              const color = props.ownerState.color;
              return props.theme.palette.textInputs[color].focused;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  MuiOutlinedInput: styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      "& .Mui-focused": {
        borderColor: (props) => {
          const color = props.ownerState.color;
          return props.theme.palette.textInputs[color].focused;
        },
      },
    },
  },
  MuiTextInput: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        "& .Mui-focused": {
          borderColor: (props) => {
            const color = props.ownerState.color;
              return props.theme.palette.textInputs[color].focused;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ...

I also tried to just set borderColor: "transparent" in all those overrides, but nothing happens. Also, if I remove the primary property from my palette, the focus color becomes blue.
Is there some override that I am missing?
Let me know if you need further details.
Thanks in advance

I was able to replicate the issue where the styles disappear when refreshing the project.
I was able to fix it by ensuring that the style override is still applied even after refreshing like this:
Code Example
export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
  const textFieldSx = {
    '.MuiInputLabel-outlined.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'green',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'green',
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form">
      <TextField label="Name" defaultValue="John Doe" sx={textFieldSx} />
    </Box>
  );
}

Demo
Stackblitz Demo

You may need to add your Error styles along with that code.

Thank you! Looks like my code was perfectly fine, the problem was the space I left before Mui-focused (my version was "& .Mui-focused"; correct version is "&.Mui-focused"). Do you know why the space is so important in this case? I mean, in all other parts of my code the overrides have a space before the class name (and also in your code, there is a space before ".MuiOutlinedInput-root"). Why this difference and how could I have known that?

The & is referring to a parent selector. It is used to represent the selector itself in a nested context Sass: Parent Selector.
You may need to identify which element you are selecting in order to give the proper specification, otherwise another class with override it.
I've updated the Stackblitz link above and added some examles using the & selector to modify children from the same parent.
